# "bash -c" vs. "dash -c"

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dash-shell

`dash -c` behaves differently from `bash -c`:

```
docker run -it ubuntu /bin/dash -c ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 sh
    7 ?        00:00:00 ps

docker run -it ubuntu /bin/bash -c ps
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
    1 ?        00:00:00 ps
```

Is there an explanation for this difference?

Comment: I'd say that bash doesn't need to run a shell to run ps on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

bash has an optimisation where the very last command in a script implicitly gets executed with `exec`. dash recently gained this optimisation as well, but not yet in the version you're using. You'll see the same behaviour with `bash -c 'exec ps'` and `dash -c 'exec ps'`.